# Trying to Create a temp table in Oracle

Tags: oracle, temp-tables

Getting an error message when trying to create a temp table. I copied this code directly from Oracle's website. I also downloaded the latest version 18.2. What am I missing here?

```
CREATE PRIVATE TEMPORARY TABLE ora$ptt_my_temp_table 
(
  id           NUMBER(10,2),
  description  VARCHAR2(20)
)
ON COMMIT PRESERVE DEFINITION;
```

Error Message:

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
CREATE PRIVATE TEMPORARY TABLE ora$ptt_my_temp_table 
(
  id           NUMBER(10,2),
  description  VARCHAR2(20)
)
ON COMMIT PRESERVE DEFINITION
Error report -
ORA-00905: missing keyword
00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Comment: Are you sure you connectig to Oracle 18c? I guess 18.2 is version of SQL Developer(client tool).

Comment: I'm use to using Microsoft SQL. How would I know if I'm connected to Oracle 18c.

Comment: You are mixing a lot of things. First of all **Microsoft SQL Server != Oracle DB**. Second client tool (SQL Developer/SSMS) != server-side database. And finally the example you posted clearly indicates that you need to connect to instance that supports private temp tables(i.e. 18c). I suggest to post screenshots of your client tool and exact query. I guess that you are connected to Oracle 11g/12c.

Comment: I know they are not the same, I was saying I'm more familiar with Mircrosoft SQL Server and Oracle DB is new to me. I'm also new to Stack Overflow. Give me a few min to upload screen shots.

Comment: Don't know why my picture is not showing up. Don't worry about it and thanks for your help. I'll keep searching.

Comment: Try `select * from v$version v where v.banner like 'Oracle Database%';` For the SQL Developer app, it should show a version number in the startup splash screen and under the standard Help > About.

Comment: The statement above works fine in 18c at [livesql.oracle.com](https://livesql.oracle.com), but gives *ORA-00905: missing keyword* in earlier versions. Voting to close.

Comment: https://oracle-base.com/articles/18c/private-temporary-tables-18c

Answer (score 3):

I presume you're not on Oracle 18c but some lower version (which doesn't know *private* temporary tables). Therefore, I suggest you run

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE ora$ptt_my_temp_table 
(
  id           NUMBER(10,2),
  description  VARCHAR2(20)
)
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;
```

and move on.

Comment: Global temporary tables are different beasts from private ones, because they are permanent structures.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS line.  That syntax is only used for **Global** Temorary Tables.  For **Private** Temporary tables, you need to use one of the following:

ON COMMIT DROP DEFINITION
This drops the table at the end of the transaction (or at the end of the session if transactions are not being used).
This is the default, so this line can be omitted if this is the behavior you want.

ON COMMIT PRESERVE DEFINITION
The table will persist beyond any transactions, but will still be deleted at the end of the session.

See: https://oracle-base.com/articles/18c/private-temporary-tables-18c